# I am trying to open Expo project on my handphone but I get an error

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I am new to React Native. 
I am trying to open my expo project on my handphone but I get some errors - see the attached pictures.  How do I fix this error? Thank you!

[Here's the error pictures [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhcbZ.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide more details how and from where you are running the expo project: windows and lan also check firewall on your PC or Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the tunnel connection and the LAN connection, it does that at times.. try using a USB cord, connect your phone to the system and make sure you turn on debugger mode on the mobile device.